# oracle PRO*C char(1) type trimmed to null?

Tags: oracle10g, type-conversion

I have a table which has a column as follows:

```
ppbacct_status  CHAR(1) default ' ' not null,
```

then I have follow pro*c:

```
EXEC SQL BEGIN DECLARE SECTION;
    sql_context ctx = NULL;
    char v_p_status_1 = ' ';
EXEC SQL END   DECLARE SECTION;

EXEC SQL select ppbacct_status into :v_p_status_1 from ppbaccount 
where exchange_type = '1' and branch_no = 1854 and stock_account = 'A001854009';

printf("|%c|, |%d|\n", v_p_status_1, v_p_status_1); // here get:  | |, |32|

EXEC SQL update ppbaccount set remark = 'a'||:v_p_status_1||'a' where exchange_type = '1' and branch_no = 1854 and stock_account = 'A001854005'; // 'aa'
```

after the last update, I get remark column as 'aa', why not 'a a', Where is the space?

Oracle Version: 10.2.0.1, with CentOS 5.5。

PRO*C flags:

```
CPP_PROFLAGS=ireclen=132 oreclen=132 \
        select_error=yes \
        mode=ansi \
        userid=$(USERID) \
        SQLCHECK=SYNTAX \
        def_sqlcode=YES \
        THREADS=YES \
        CODE=CPP \
        CHAR_MAP=CHARF \
        CPP_SUFFIX=cpp \
        PARSE=PARTIAL \
        CLOSE_ON_COMMIT=YES \
        MAXOPENCURSORS=60 \
        DEFINE=USE_PRO_C \
        HOLD_CURSOR=YES \
        PREFETCH=200 \
        include=$(ORACLE_HOME)/precomp/public  \
        include=$(ORACLE_HOME)/oci/include  \
        include=$(FBASE_HOME) \
        include=/usr/lib/gcc-lib/i386-redhat-linux/$(GCC_VER)/include
```